# Pandas groupby function with max aggregation performance is slow. groupby Performance improvement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a dataframe having around 16,000 rows and I'm performing max aggregation of one column and grouping it by another one.

```
df.groupby(['col1']).agg({'col2': 'max'}).reset_index()
```

It takes 1.97s. I'd like to improve it's performance. Request you suggest in lines of utilizing numpy or vectorization.

Datatype both columns are object.

```
%%timeit
df.groupby(['col1']).agg({'col2': 'max'}).reset_index()

1.97 s ± 42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each
```

Comment: I would try converting `df['col1']` to categorical beforehand

Comment: It is categorical only.

Comment: @BallpointBen, It apparently seems that having 'col1' as int improves performance twice.

Comment: Yeah that's true. This works for groupby. While aggregating if you can convert your column to int then it works faster. For my case it was load id which is string and can be changed to int as well and aggregation it much more faster for integers.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with datatypes and changed datatype of col2 to integer and it reduced the run time significantly.

```
%%timeit
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(int)
df.groupby(['col1']).agg({'col2': 'max'}).reset_index()

6.58 ms ± 74.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Aggregation of integer will be faster than string.